# Razor not binding NULLABLE value properties?

Tags: asp.net-core, .net-core, razor

I have an MVC controller action that receives an object which has these two properties:

```
public int PropOne { get; set; }

public int? PropTwo { get; set; }
```

My html form contains two select boxes:

```
<select asp-items="listCodes"
    asp-for="@Model.MyObject.PropOne"
    value="@Model.MyObject.PropOne">
</select>

<select asp-items="listCodes"
    asp-for="@Model.MyObject.PropTwo"
    value="@Model.MyObject.PropTwo">
</select>
```

`listCodes` has two records, one with a value of 0, the other a value of 1.

I change both select boxes to choose the option with value = 1.

When I POST the form, the controller's parameter has property `PropOne` populated with the value `1` as expected.

But property `PropTwo` is always `null`. Why might this be?

If I change the second select box to have a name attribute (as below), then it works as expected and the controller's object parameter has property `PropTwo` set to `1` a expected.

```
<select asp-items="listCodes"
    name="PropTwo"
    value="@Model.MyObject.PropTwo">
</select>
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to check the parameter in your action,.net core bind data with `name` attribute.For example,if `name="PropTwo"` works,your parameter in action may looks like `int PropTwo`.And since you have usedasp-for="@Model.MyObject.PropOne",there's no need to use `value="@Model.MyObject.PropTwo"`.Here is a working demo:

View:

```
<form method="post">
    <select asp-for="@Model.MyObject.PropOne">
        <option value="0">0</option>
        <option value="1">1</option>

    </select>

    <select asp-for="@Model.MyObject.PropTwo">
        <option value="0">0</option>
        <option value="1">1</option>

    </select>
    <input type="submit" value="submit" />
</form>
```

action:

```
public IActionResult TestSelect(TestModel1 t) {
            return View(new TestModel1 {);
        }
```

result:
[image]

Comment: The action only has 1 paramter, an object which has the two properties mentioned in my post.

Comment: What is the name of the object in action?As I mentioned in my answer,.net core bind data with `name` attribute,you need to make sure the name of parameter is right.

Comment: The action expected a parameter named `foo`. So foo.PropOne and foo.PropTwo would have been valid HTML entity names. But my names were MyObject.PropOne and MyObject.PropTwo. The first of those two would bind, the second would not. I don't know why the first would bind at all because there is no parameter named "MyObject", that's the name of the type expected. And if it matched based on property name only, why didn't MyObject.PropTwo also bind?

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution. My action looked like this:

```
public JsonResult Save(MyObject foo)
```

More context:

```
// Model in the razor file is an instance of:
public class MyObjectWrapper
{
    public MyObject MyObject;
}

public class MyObject
{
    public int PropOne { get; set; }
    public int? PropTwo { get; set; }
}
```

Both select box's properly bind to properties in parameter `foo` when I do:

```
@{
    MyObject foo = Model.MyObject;
}

<select asp-items="listCodes" asp-for="@foo.PropOne"></select>

<select asp-items="listCodes" asp-for="@foo.PropTwo"></select>
```

I guess the question I'm left with is why did it properly bind `PropOne` before? If it ignore the action's parameter name and did the binding solely based uopn the name of a property on the action's parameter, why did it only do so for one of the two submitted names?